# Can I repeat a Union Join in Oracle SQL for different values defined by another query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, union

I have the following query that returns the decile for a group of users based on their mark per programme:

```
SELECT prog_code,
    user_code,
    user_mark,
  NTILE(10) over (order by user_mark DESC) DECILE
FROM grade_result
where user_mark IS NOT NULL
and prog_year = '2011'
AND prog_code = 'ALPHA'
```

I need to run this for a total of 40 different prog_code values at the same time, which could be joined together via 39 union joins, but this seems massively inefficient (I can't run this as single select statement as the decile would then be for *all* programmes, rather than by programme). Is there a way I can get the query to repeat (loop?) for each of these 40 values as a Union, without having to enter each one myself?

I can return the programme codes and a rownum in a separate query or subquery if this is any use:

```
ROWNUM         PROG_CODE

1              ALPHA
2              BETA
3              GAMMA
4              DELTA
5              ECHO
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not add a query_partition_clause - `NTILE(10) over (partition by prog_code order by user_mark DESC) DECILE
` ?

Comment: I think you should look into using `PARTITION BY prog_code`. If you need a reference - this seems like a good one: http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2010/11/really-cool-ntile-window-function.html

Comment: That's it! Jeez, seems so obvious now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you simply use the partition clause in your NTILE function?

```
SELECT prog_code,
    user_code,
    user_mark,
  NTILE(10) over (PARTITION BY prog_code ORDER BY user_mark DESC) DECILE
FROM grade_result
where user_mark IS NOT NULL
and prog_year = '2011';
```

Comment: Yes, many thanks. I don't have a lot of experience with the Analytic functions so I'm glad to see there is such a simple solution.